# Integrating MongoDB with OpenESB

Tags: mongodb, soa

I have been tasked with investigating the integration of MongoDB into SOA, using OpenESB.

From what I have read so far, it seems to me that there is no support for this out of the box with either MongoDB or OpenESB. I would assume that some kind of plugin on OpenESB would be necessary in order to send requests to Mongo (while Mongo is a database, it does not really have a JDBC driver because the semantics don't really match).

Being relatively new to the concepts of SOA, I would appreciate some pointers, links to good documentation/articles, and so-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Orientation is less about the technology and more about the design. I am cetain you can use these technologies in a SOA without any question, but they are just that, implementation choices. In the same way Java, .NET can be implemenation choices for applications.

Any way back to your question, MongoDB is a persistance store, so in a SOA it would sit behind a service layer that would shield the upstream users from this fact, you could at a later date swop it out with the next most useful, popular,  persistance store and the users would be none the wiser.

Same thing for OpenESB, ESB is a pattern you can use to implement certain aspects of service orientation, namely routing, pub/sub, message transformation etc.. Your implementation choice is just OpenESB, so do the same thing, shield the implemenation choice behind a stable interface.

The best way I now of to implement theses interfaces is to create capability focused interfaces, i.e. focused on the what not on the how.

Here are some practical examples of how to build a SOA using WCF, I realise that .Net may not be your implementation choice, but the principles hold true as they as SOA principles.

I would suggest you read articles by Thomas Erl and Roger Sessions, this will give you a firm handle on what SOA is all about.

[Building a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Building-Service-Orientated-Architecture)

[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

[Achieving integrity in a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Achieving-Non-Functional-Requirements-for-a-Service-Oriented-Software-Platform-Integrity)

[Why your SOA should be like a VW Beetle](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Why-your-Service-Orientated-Architecture-SOA-needs-to-be-like-a-VW-Beetle)

[SOA explained for your boss](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/soa-with-wcf)

[WCF Service Performance](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/WCF-Service-Performance)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create MongoDB component for openesb.

1> create wsdl services for integration.
2> java pojo will use java-driver-for-mongo-db.

this component will be generic and communication will be wsdl call with xml payloads.

for transformation you can use xsl's.